# Node.js collection stream?

Tags: node.js, stream

I am manually parsing an XML document from a readStream. I only get one node at a time and have to build up the tree as new nodes come in. I don't want to pipe data to the next stream until I have completely built this XML tree.

Is there a stream that says "I won't send you data, until I have received all the data I need"?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end This might help since end fires off at the end of the incoming stream--you'd then have your completed collection of data.

Comment: You might find the answer by inspecting what https://github.com/maxogden/concat-stream does.